# SetActive true/false only once when game install first time unity?

Tags: unity

In my unity game I try to give player instruction how to play but it only in first level and first time when game install so how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Store the information about having showed the tutorial in permanent local storage, such as:

- A file (if file doesn't exist, run tutorial and create file)
- The content of a file (if file doesn't exist, run tutorial and set a flag in file)
- A registry entry (if registry entry doesn't exist or is 0, run tutorial and set entry to 1)

Additionally, allow players to run the tutorial on their own, and also allow the players to skip the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PlayerPrefs to store an int value to achieve this. See the following example.

---

In this example, I have stored a key named "Test" in preferences.

1. Check if the preferences has the key.
   `bool exists = PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Test");`
2. If the key exists, then don't display the instructions.
3. Otherwise, display the instructions and use the following code to add the key. `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Test",1);`